# How can I prevent checkout of certain directories in SVN?

Tags: svn

I have a directory structure in my SVN repository which is pretty standard:

```
/project1
   /trunk
   /branches
      /branch1
      /branch2
      ...
   /tags
/project2
   /trunk
   /branches
      ...
```

I'm using Apache with mod_dav_svn to host the repository.

I would like to prevent people from accidentally checking out the root of a project or the root of the entire repository, which needlessly downloads many, many gigabytes of files, and usually causes all kinds of problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `mod_dontdothat` for this. See the [docs](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/tags/1.6.9/contrib/server-side/mod_dontdothat/README):

> Specifically, it's designed to keep
>   users from doing things that are
>   particularly hard on the server, like
>   checking out the root of the tree, or
>   the tags or branches directories.  It
>   works by sticking an input filter in
>   front of all REPORT requests and
>   looking for dangerous types of
>   requests.  If it finds any, it returns
>   a 403 Forbidden error.

Comment: Nice, didn't know about that one. It seems rather old. Does it still work with subversion 1.5 and 1.6?

Comment: I updated the link to something more recent, and yes it should still work

Answer (score 1):

Check out [the section in the SVN book about Path-Based Authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html).

You could deny access to the root by default and allow read(write) access to the individual projects.